# how can i pre-process resources in gradle springboot devtools?

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

I want to pre-compile sass into css.

`addResources` flag(`true`) does not solve this problem.

Spring devtools just load raw resources into `build`.

There are some gradle node plugin, gulp plugin.

When `processResoureces` task is called, `bootRun` task running on the server resets `build` directory and re-copy raw resources into `build`. So gulp, webpack, etc plugin can't do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rene](http://How%20to%20define%20a%20preprocessing%20task%20for%20android%20build?) has given a solution in gradle blog

> all those "internal" tasks are created within the
>   project.afterEvaluate closure which means that they can't be
>   referenced directly in the build.gradle. As a workaround you can move
>   the dependsOn declaration in the afterEvaluate phase too.
>
> ```
> project.afterEvaluate{
>     prepareDebugDependencies.dependsOn("generateMyAssets")
> }
> ```

Resource Link: [How to define a preprocessing task for android build?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-define-a-preprocessing-task-for-android-build/6147)

### UPDATE#1:

Q1: [Why bootRun task re-copy resources?](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)

> If devtools has been added to your project it will automatically
>   monitor your application for changes. Alternatively, you can also run
>   the application so that your static classpath resources (i.e. in
>   src/main/resources by default) are reloadable in the live application,
>   which can be helpful at development time.
>
> ```
> bootRun {
>     addResources = true
> }
> ```
>
> Making static classpath resources reloadable means that bootRun does
>   not use the output of the processResources task, i.e., when invoked
>   using bootRun, your application will use the resources in their
>   unprocessed form.

Comment: How can i know internal task of spring boot? I don't know Why bootRun task re-copy resources. `processResources finalizedBy sometask` in `project.afterEvaluate {}` doesn't work too.

Comment: When i turn off `addResources`, resources are not reloadable. When i turn on `addResources`, resources just copied into `build`. so resources how to? Do i have to parse directory structure(templates, js resources, stylesheet resources) and watch them using gulp etc and copy them manually into `build` ????

Comment: It's funny. First bootRun, A task i attacted to `processResources` works fine (like `processResources.finalizedBy babelJStask`), but in next `processResources`, the task goes wrong.(the output of babelJStask disappear. Nonetheless i set task graph dependency like above. maybe it looks like overwritten by `processResources` or `internal task`)